# Why in a simple loop I lose fetchAll's values of a sqlite3's table using python?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, loops

I need to print some rows from an sqlite3's table using python3, but into the loop I get none value. following my code:

```
import sqlite3
db=sqlite3.connect('db.db')
cdb=db.cursor()
cdb.execute('create table if not exists table1 (field1,field2,field3)')
cdb.execute('insert into table1 values (?,?,?)',(1,2,3))
db.commit()
cdb.execute('insert into table1 values (?,?,?)',(4,5,6))
db.commit()
cdb.execute('insert into table1 values (?,?,?)',(1,7,8))
db.commit()
cdb.execute('select * from table1')
for i in range(len(cdb.fetchall())):
    if cdb.fetchone()[0]==1:print(cdb.fetchone())
db.close()
```

my error message:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `cdb.fetchall()` consumes the iterator and is pointless, so remove it:

```py
for row in cdb.execute('select * from table1'):
    # do something with row
```

As described in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall).

Comment: sorry always same error message

Comment: @Tommy in which line does the error occur?

Comment: print(cdb.fetchall())

Comment: @Tommy that code occurs neither in your question nor in my answer. Have you tried implementing my suggestion?

Comment: sure i did: for row in cdb.execute('select * from table1'):print(cdb.fetchall())

Comment: @Tommy and then what do you inside the for loop? A simple `print(row)` would be a starting point.

Comment: @Tommy glad to hear that! Please consider marking the answer as accepted and/or upvoting to complete the Q/A cycle.

Answer (score 1):

After you `fetchall` the cursor point to nothing, so if you fetch anything it returns `None`.

to see what happend after commit the data just try:

```
cdb.execute('select * from table1')

print(cdb.fetchall()) # Return the data
print(cdb.fetchone()) # Return : None

db.close()
```

to fix this you could execute the sql again before the `fetchone` witch will be slow

I recommend doing this:

```
cdb.execute('select * from table1')

data = cdb.fetchall()
for i in data:
    if i[0] == 1: print(i)

db.close()
```